# Backbone model+collection / TypeScriptand compilation compiles weirdly

Tags: typescript, backbone.js

I have a class that looks like this

```
export class MyClass extends backbone.Model {
    idAttribute: string = "Name";
    private MyProperty: new backbone.Collection<MyCollectionItemClass>();

...
```

in JavaScript:

```
private MyProperty: new backbone.Collection<MyCollectionItemClass>();
```

compiles into:

```
_this.MyProperty= ();
```

Which gives:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

---

Just tested:
If I remove `private`

```
MyProperty: new backbone.Collection<MyCollectionItemClass>();
```

Results in the same code.

---

As somebody asked for a more complete example:
TypeScript:

```
import _ = require("underscore");
import backbone = require("backbone");

export class MyClass extends backbone.Model {
    private MyProperty: new backbone.Collection<MyCollectionItemClass>();
}

export class MyCollectionItemClass extends backbone.Model {
}
```

Compiles into JavaScript:

```
var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || (function () {
    var extendStatics = Object.setPrototypeOf ||
        ({ __proto__: [] } instanceof Array && function (d, b) { d.__proto__ = b; }) ||
        function (d, b) { for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p]; };
    return function (d, b) {
        extendStatics(d, b);
        function __() { this.constructor = d; }
        d.prototype = b === null ? Object.create(b) : (__.prototype = b.prototype, new __());
    };
})();
define(["require", "exports", "backbone"], function (require, exports, backbone) {
    "use strict";
    exports.__esModule = true;
    var MyClass = (function (_super) {
        __extends(MyClass, _super);
        function MyClass() {
            var _this = _super !== null && _super.apply(this, arguments) || this;
            _this.MyProperty = ();
            return _this;
        }
        return MyClass;
    }(backbone.Model));
    exports.MyClass = MyClass;
    var MyCollectionItemClass = (function (_super) {
        __extends(MyCollectionItemClass, _super);
        function MyCollectionItemClass() {
            return _super !== null && _super.apply(this, arguments) || this;
        }
        return MyCollectionItemClass;
    }(backbone.Model));
    exports.MyCollectionItemClass = MyCollectionItemClass;
});
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "module": "amd"
  },
  "compileOnSave": true
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I have added a more complete example.

Comment: Would moving the declaration of `MyCollectionItemClass` above `MyClass` change something?

Comment: Just tried, no change.